# Fix Review by same line with review

Tags: review

http://demo.emthemes.com/gala-titanshop/index.php/crucial-1gb-pc4200-ddr2-533mhz-memory.html

like you see, Review by [nickname] is same line with review but i dont want that, i want it look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit the template `/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/review/product/view/list.phtml` and mvoe this line

`<a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewUrl($_review->getId()) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_review->getTitle()) ?></a> <?php echo $this->__('Review by <span>%s</span>', $this->escapeHtml($_review->getNickname())) ?>` at the end of the `foreach` loop.